# After close the question, why do you delete it?

Tags: discussion

Link of the question: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50591

A guy marked my question as off-topic.

Ok, then I researched on my own, and get the answer: https://github.com/kuchaguangjie/eric-blog/wiki/Network-delay-between-processes-on-the-same-host-VS-on-different-hosts

Ｓince the other user on StackExchange want to know the result, so I talked with him a bit, and provided my research result on the question.

Then that guy `Ron Maupin` who closed the question, deleted the question. Stopped us from communication.

From my opinion, this is very bad behavior, feels this site is governed by dictators, and very dark.

I strongly request to undelete the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) is explicitly *not* a discussion forum. We have [Network Engineering Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations) for discussions, including off-topic subjects. You can hold the discussion you were trying to have on the chat site, but it is inappropriate for the Q&A site.

From the [Network Engineering Tour](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) page:

> This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion
>   forum. There's no chit-chat.

The sheer number of comments on the question (23) was out of hand. I deleted the question because it was being used as a discussion forum, rather than the chat site.

Comment: What we trying to do exactly is to get an answer, I added a possible solution to the post, since no answer could be added after you close it. And if you want people to talk on chat site, then improve this site, to add a hint link to chat site just like what StackOverflow site would do. The ultimate purpose of this site is to help people get the solution, and that is what we trying to do, and from my opinion that's what you are trying your best to prevent people from achieve that !

Comment: And about the 23 comments, half of them are there, with you involved to discuss with you, not between us! From my view you lose the point the site, it's about get things done / solved, not forcing people spend twice times or even more time to discuss thus non-sense ... without making any change, or help any people !

Comment: You are trying to get an answer to a question that is not allowed on the site. You can do that on [chat]. It is not appropriate to ask home improvement questions on [networkengineering.se] (there is an SE site for that), nor is it appropriate to ask host/server/VM questions (there are various SE sites for that). As it explains on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page that was linked for you, "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._"

Comment: I think I would stop "talking" this here, and continue to do what I am interested in.

Comment: @EricWang, just because a question is about networking, doesn't mean it is on-topic for [networkengineering.se]. We are more than happy to answer your on-topic questions, but please take your other questions to the appropriate site(s) (including [chat], for which you have enough reputation).